# Page is jumping to top on first tab click

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, tabs, telerik

I am using telerik Tabstrip like this:

```
<div style="width:100%;height:100%;">
 <div style="height:40%">

      //Here is my grid 

</div>

<div style="height:40%">
 @{
            Html.Telerik().TabStrip()
                .Name("DetailTab")

                .Items(parent =>
                {
                                parent.Add().Text("Tab1")
                        .LoadContentFrom("Action", "Controller")
                        .Selected(false);

                    parent.Add().Text("Tab2")
                        .LoadContentFrom("Action", "Controller")
                        .Selected(true);


                }).Render();
        }
</div>

</div>
```

On click on each tab content will be loaded with ajax.
On first click on each tab page is jumping  to top , and I can't figure out ,why I have this behavior.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2):

Probably because you don't use `event.preventDefault()` function.

```
$('.myTabs').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  // other stuff
});
```

Comment: Probably , but I cant do this because I am using telerik tabstrip ...doing this I need to make my custom tabs...